# FIFO using vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am writing a VHDL for fifo , but when i simulate   there is no output?i cantt view the output in behavioral simulation.its like There's no data in data_in for read to be writing to the output of fifo.In my code is   to write data into the FIFO first push the data onto the DataIn bus and then strobe the WriteEn input high for one clock cycle.

```
library IEEE;
        use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
        use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
        use std.textio.all;
        use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


        entity fifo_mem is
        port (    clk : in std_logic;
                  reset : in std_logic;
                  enr : in std_logic;   
                  enw : in std_logic;   
                  data_in : in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);     --input data
                  data_out : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);    --output data
                  fifo_empty : out std_logic;     
                  fifo_full : out std_logic   );
        end fifo_mem;
         architecture Behavioral of fifo_mem is
        type fifo_type is array(0 to 10) of bit_vector (15 downto 0);
        signal memory : fifo_type :=(others => (others => '0'));   
        signal readptr,writeptr : integer := 0;  --read and write pointers.
        signal empty,full : std_logic ;


     impure function InitRamFromFile (RamFileName : in string) return fifo_type is
        FILE RamFile : text is in RamFileName;
        variable RamFileLine : line;
        variable RAM : fifo_type;
        begin
        for I in 0 to 10  loop
        readline (RamFile, RamFileLine);
        read (RamFileLine, RAM(I));
        end loop;
        return RAM;
        end function;

     signal RAM : fifo_type :=InitRamFromFile("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\file\file1.txt");


begin
    fifo_empty <= empty;
    fifo_full <= full;

    process(Clk,reset)
    --this is the number of elements stored in fifo at a time.
    --this variable is used to decide whether the fifo is empty or full.
    variable num_elem : integer := 0;  
    begin
    if(reset = '1') then
        data_out <= (others => '0');
        empty <= '0';
        full <= '0';
        readptr <= 0;
        writeptr <= 0;
        num_elem := 0;
    elsif(rising_edge(Clk)) then
        if(enr = '1' and empty = '0') then  --read
            data_out <=to_stdlogicvector(RAM(readptr));
            readptr <= readptr + 1;      
            num_elem := num_elem-1;
        end if;
        if(enw ='1' and full = '0') then    --write
         RAM(writeptr)<= to_bitvector(data_in);
            writeptr <= writeptr +1;  
            num_elem := num_elem+1;
        end if;

         if(readptr = 10) then      --resetting read pointer.
            readptr <= 0;
        end if;
        if(writeptr = 10) then        --resetting write pointer.
            writeptr <= 0;
        end if; 
        --setting empty and full flags.
        if(num_elem = 0) then
            empty <= '1';
        else
            empty <= '0';
        end if;
        if(num_elem = 10) then
            full <= '1';
        else
            full <= '0';
        end if;
    end if; 
    end process;

    end Behavioral;
```

Comment: It's your testbench that would put data on `data_in` and you haven't shown us that, so ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get a useful answer if you follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, what is happening, what were you expecting to happen? (There's no output, I can't view the output doesn't really answer those questions.) Secondly, provide something executable so that someone else can easily see what you're seeing. Finally, just supply the minimum code required to reproduce the problem. These last two are called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JHBonarius, no you are wrong i didnt deleted any question , i dont know why you are like this ?if you dont dont answer mee ,so dont lets the good people answer  mee. thankyou

Comment: @BrianDrummond, thanks for your reply , okey i will write my testbench

Comment: A [mcve] would also imply the contents of file1.txt, although why one would initialize memory in a FIFO isn't apparent here and a FIFO 11 deep seems a bit odd.